# hijackWindow() context created for

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7, visual-c++-2010

I'm developing desktop Qt 4.7.1 application for Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2010 and cl compiler. OpenGL widgets are used.

Some time ago I started to receive messages like the following ones during my application initialization:

```
hijackWindow() context created for QWidget(0x1c8f070, name = "x1") 1 
hijackWindow() context created for QGroupBox(0x1c8f5f8, name = "x2") 2 
hijackWindow() context created for QGroupBox(0x19f70b0, name = "x3") 3 
hijackWindow() context created for QGroupBox(0x19f9d40, name = "x4") 4 
hijackWindow() context created for QGraphicsView(0x19fae28, name = "x5") 5
```

What could be the reason for these messages? How can I disable window hijacking since it consumes a lot of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of the time consuming was in using opengl graphics system instead of raster one. So the solution is to add the following parameter to command line:

```
-graphicssystem raster
```

Or to build the whole Qt with this flag.

Comment: Raster subsystem is no OpenGL, which you asked about. And your problem wasn't quite a problem, just a debug statement. But yeah, you can avoid that by not using OpenGL :-D

Comment: Suddenly OpenGL widgets are still working fine even with raster graphics engine =)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a debug message emitted by Qt library when creating a GL context for a widget. I think this message should not appear if you use release versions of Qt libraries (they must be built with `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT` or `QT_NO_DEBUG` macros defined, which disables calls to `qDebug`).

Comment: I've just tried to build both application and libraries in release configuration and run - result is the same.

Comment: @DairT'arg: Uh, its been a long time since I used Qt... It seems like these things are making it into release these days. To get rid of it, you have to install a custom message handler. See http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler

Comment: we have absolutely same custom-built configuration of Qt, same visual studio, same OS and same source code (it's just a straight copy) on two separate computers. The specified "hijack problem" exists only on one of them. So I wonder what could cause it?

Comment: @DairT'arg: Well, something is obviously different (qt project config? environment variables?). Computers are very deterministic and there is no magic. I don't know the answer w/o debugging, unfortunately. I'd get source code for the version of Qt you are using and grep for 'hijackWindow() context created for' line. Set breakpoints in there and debug why it is called on one machine and not on another. If called on both, then one just suppresses debug messages, that you can debug further...

Comment: I've found the reason. If interesting please see my comment below.